# 22.04 Ubuntu Live USB Has Pink Headers

Tags: live-usb, colors, 22.04

I sort of like the pink header on the 22.04 Ubuntu live USB, but on the actual install, that is not there.  The only themes are on the accent color.

I wonder why this is not included in the actual install?

How does one get those pink headers?  Strange the screenshot does not show this very slight pink header.
[image]

Comment: It's probably an issue with the live session graphics drivers. Not an intentional theme.

Comment: That would probably explain why the screenshot was not showing this.  However, perhaps I stumbled upon a really nice new look.  It was very subtle, but looked really nice.

Comment: xorg login gives this effect.  I get flameshot working as well too.  Double click on the header on google chrome also maximizes the window.  The screenshot posted above also now shows that same effect, but not seen in wayland.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I switch to xorg login, I get those pink headers like in the LiveUSB.  ...Cool...
I also get my screenshot tools to work properly as well.